# How do I make a javafx node adapt to it´s parent?

Tags: java, javafx

Example:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="HomeController">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="vBoxParent" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity">
         <children>
            <MenuBar fx:id="menubar" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="800.0">

        ...
```

With this code, the stage opens fullsize, but the menubar isn´t covering all the lenght. What do I have to add?

Comment: Make the `VBox` the root?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the MenuBar to take the full size of VBox, you can replace VBox with MenuBar, placing MenuBar directly in AnchorPane, and giving Anchor Pane Constraints to the MenuBar (to be responsive).

If you want to keep VBox for some reason, you can change the MenuBar properties:

- set Vgrow to: allways (allways increase the vertical length)
- set Max Width to: MAX_VALUE

I recommend you to use SceneBuilder, to easily find functions and preview changes.